# How is the probability of removing a candy from a bag affected when the bag contains both known and unknown quantities of the same type of candy?

Tags: probability

There is a bag of $100$ candies. When initially filled there is $1$ known purple candy added to the bag, then there are $6$ flavors (purple, red, green, blue, yellow, orange) that are randomly added to the bag with equal probability of being added for the remaining $99$.

You remove (and do not replace) one candy from the bag and it is purple. What is the probability that a purple candy is removed next?

To my understanding there is a $17.67$ %probability of the first removed candy being purple $(\frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{6})$. Initially I thought removing a second purple candy would be a simple $\frac{1}{6}$ probability since a purple candy has become known which would account for the first known purple candy put in the bag.

However I then realized that it is unknown if the purple candy that you have removed is the same as the known purple candy added initially to the bag or a randomly added purple candy. How does this uncertainty of which purple candy has been removed affect the probability of removing a second purple candy?

Comment: It might be worth trying with a bag of two candies first.  I think the probability of removing a purple candy first is $\frac 7{12}$ and given that you do the probability of drawing a second purple candy is then $\frac27$

Comment: So your $\frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{6}$ is not quite right, and should be $\frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{99}{100} = 17.5\%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth trying with a bag of two candies first. I think the probability of removing a purple candy first is $\frac12+\frac12\frac16=\frac7{12}$ and given that you do the probability of drawing a second purple candy is then $\dfrac{\frac12\frac16+\frac12\frac16 1}{\frac12+\frac12\frac16} = \frac 27$.

So with $100$ your $\frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{6}$ is not quite right for the probability of the first being purple, and should be $\frac{1}{100} + \frac{99}{100}\frac{1}{6} = 17.5\%$

and the conditional probability the second is purple given the first is purple is $$\dfrac{\frac{1}{100}\frac{1}{6} + \frac{99}{100}\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{99} + \frac{98}{99}\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\frac{1}{100} + \frac{99}{100}\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{11}{63}\approx 17.46\%$$